# Convergence of series of circles

Tags: calculus, geometry

Let $\Gamma_i$ denote circle of radius $r_i=\frac{1}{2^i}$, $\omega_i$ its center, $i\ge1$. Series is constructed the following way: $\Gamma_1$, $\Gamma_2$, $\Gamma_3$ touch externally, for every $i\ge4$ $\Gamma_i$ touches externally $\Gamma_{i-2}$ and $\Gamma_{i-1}$ so that, distance between centers of $\omega_i$ and $\omega_{i-3}$ is maximum possible. I need to find out if this construct "converges", i.e. if there is a $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\angle\omega_1\omega_2\omega_n$.

Here is my attempt.
Lemma ${1}$: line segments $\omega_i\omega_{i+1}$,  $i\ge{2k+1}$, $k\in{N}$, are parallel.
Proof: Consider $\bigtriangleup{\omega_{i-1}\omega_{i}\omega_{i+1}}$. By the law of cosines $\\cos \angle\omega_{i-1}\omega_i\omega_{i+1}=\frac{-(r_{i-1}+r_{i+1})^2+(r_{i}+r_{i+1})^2+(r_{i}+r_{i-1})^2}{2(r_{i}+r_{i-1})(r_{i}+r_{i+1})}=\frac{-(\frac{1}{2^{i-1}}+\frac{1}{2^{i+1}})^2+(\frac{1}{2^{i}}+\frac{1}{2^{i+1}})^2+(\frac{1}{2^{i}}+\frac{1}{2^{i-1}})^2}{2(\frac{1}{2^{i}}+\frac{1}{2^{i-1}})(\frac{1}{2^{i}}+\frac{1}{2^{i+1}})}=\frac{-\frac{25}{2^{2i+2}}+\frac{9}{2^{2i+2}}+\frac{36}{2^{2i+2}}}{2(\frac{3}{2^{i+1}})(\frac{6}{2^{i+1}})}=\frac{20}{36}=\frac{5}{9}={\cos \angle\omega_{1}\omega_2\omega_{3}}$

Lemma ${2}$: line segments $\omega_i\omega_{i+2}$,  $i\ge{2k}$, $k\in{N}$, all lie on a line.

Proof: Consider $\bigtriangleup{\omega_{i}\omega_{i+1}\omega_{i+2}}$. By the law of cosines $\cos \angle\omega_{i}\omega_{i+2}\omega_{i+1}=\frac{-(r_{i}+r_{i+1})^2+(r_{i}+r_{i+2})^2+(r_{i+1}+r_{i+2})^2}{2(r_{i}+r_{i+2})(r_{i+1}+r_{i+2})}=\frac{-(\frac{1}{2^{i}}+\frac{1}{2^{i+1}})^2+(\frac{1}{2^{i}}+\frac{1}{2^{i+2}})^2+(\frac{1}{2^{i+1}}+\frac{1}{2^{i+2}})^2}{2(\frac{1}{2^{i}}+\frac{1}{2^{i+2}})(\frac{1}{2^{i+1}}+\frac{1}{2^{i+2}})}=\frac{-\frac{9*4}{2^{2i+4}}+\frac{25}{2^{2i+4}}+\frac{9}{2^{2i+4}}}{2(\frac{5}{2^{i+2}})(\frac{3}{2^{i+2}})}={-\frac{1}{15}}$.

Similarly, line segments $\omega_i\omega_{i+2}$,  $i\ge{2k+1}$, $k\in{N}$, all lie on a line.

I can't figure out, if it imply convergence, and if it does, why?